# -d is unexpected at this time in Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

Using Git Bash on Windows 10. When trying to commit work on my branch I do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit msg"
```

The latter command gives this message:

```
-d is unexpected at this time
```

After running `GIT_TRACE=2 git commit -m "msg"` I get the following:

```
`08:25:51.133862 git.c:371  trace: built-in: git 'commit' '-m'`
`08:25:51.188903 run-command.c:350  trace: run_command: '.git/hooks/pre-commit'`
`-d was unexpected at this time.`
```

I've never encountered this before, and it only happened recently on my current project, meaning I don't know what is causing this or what I did to cause this. I was able to commit just fine until the last couple of days.

How can I fix this?

Comment: And what *exact* command throws the above error?

Comment: After typing `git commit -m "commit msg"`, and hitting enter, the above error appears...

Comment: Is there an `alias` in picture? There is no `-d` in your command list...

Comment: @anishsane: I'm not sure where `-d` is coming from. This NEVER appeared until yesterday, I was able to commit just fine until then. I was hoping someone here knew what `-d` was

Comment: Check whether something has been aliased and/or check your hooks.

Comment: I agree with others, you most probably have an alias for commit. You can check alias by `git config -l` for local and `git config --global -l` for global configs.

Comment: Run `GIT_TRACE=2 git commit -m "the message"` to see where and when the message is printed. It could be a (new) hook.

Comment: @j6t I have edited the question in response to your comment

Comment: Check your hooks.

Answer (score 0):

check your hooks.
In my case, i copy hooks folder from other working git and replace it.